# Render single record from API with Axios and React

Tags: reactjs, axios, strapi

with Strapi as backend, Axios and React, I am trying to render a single record from a list of records (no problem here with the list). For the single record, I use useParams and the API call is done. I can see my datas in the console. My data structure is as follows :

[image]

The problem comes when I need to render this single data above. I get an error that says :

[image]

This error I don't get when I render all my records, only with the specific one.
Therefore, I cannot render this specific record properly and I am stuck here. Many thanks for your help. Here is my code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Table, TableContainer, Thead, Td, Th, Tr, Tbody } from "@chakra-ui/react";

function ClubDisplay  () {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [clubs, setClubs] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/adversaires/'+id)
        .then( res => {
          const fetchedClubs = res.id;
          setClubs(fetchedClubs);
          console.log(res)
        });
    }, []);
return (
    <TableContainer>
    <Table size='lg'>
        <Thead>
            <Tr>
                <Th>ID club</Th>
            </Tr>
        </Thead>
                <Tbody>
        {
        clubs.map((club, index) => {
            return <tr key={index}>
                <td>{club.id}</td>
            </tr>
            }
        )}                                                           
                </Tbody>
    </Table>
    </TableContainer>
)
}
export default ClubDisplay;
```

Comment: You need to do `res.data.id`

Comment: `map` is used with an array, I don't an array in your `res`

Comment: With {res.data.id}, I get an error (cannor read properties of undefined (reading data). And for the second comment, many thanks for your help, but I cannot see how to solve this, I am sorry.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to map? you are trying to assign the id which is a number not an array (which btw you are not assigning correctly) to clubs??

Comment: Hi. What I am trying to map is the data I get from the API. The id in the axios request is the one coming from the complete list of "clubs". With useParams, I retrieve that id, can call the API and then get the correct specific "club" data in the console. Each club has his own id, yes, and then some attributes (comite, numeroclub, etc...). I really don't know how to manage these datas correctly once I get them (I see them in the console), you are absolutely correct. I am getting lost, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code with this :

```
 const { id } = useParams();
const [club, setClub] = useState(null); // Single club object, not an array

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:1337/api/adversaires/${id}`)
        .then(res => {
            const fetchedClub = res.data.data; 
            setClub(fetchedClub);
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching club:", error);
        });
}, [id]);

    and also change :
   

      <TableContainer>
                <Table size='lg'>
                    <Thead>
                        <Tr>
                            <Th>ID club</Th>
                        </Tr>
                    </Thead>
                    <Tbody>
                        {club && ( // Conditional rendering to check if club exists or not 
                            <Tr>
                                <Td>{club.id}</Td>
                                
                            </Tr>
                        )}
                    </Tbody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I could make it work finally and get the details of each record in my detail page.